# Get back newly inserted row in Postgres with sqlx

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, sqlx

I use https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx to make queries to Postgres.

Is it possible to get back the whole row data when inserting a new row?

Here is the query I run:

```
result, err := Db.Exec("INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1)", user.Name)
```

Or should I just use my existing `user` struct as the source of truth about the new entry in the database?

Comment: PostgreSQL supports `RETURNING` syntax for `INSERT` statements. Example: `INSERT INTO users(...) VALUES(...) RETURNING id, name, foo, bar`

Comment: Can you please put it as an answer and I will mark it as a correct one?

Answer (score 4):

Here is docs about transaction of `sqlx`:

> The result has two possible pieces of data: LastInsertId() or RowsAffected(), the availability of which is driver dependent. In MySQL, for instance, LastInsertId() will be available on inserts with an auto-increment key, but in PostgreSQL, this information can only be retrieved from a normal row cursor by using the RETURNING clause.

So I made a complete demo for how to execute transaction using `sqlx`, the demo will create an address row in `addresses` table and then create a user in `users` table using the new `address_id` PK as `user_address_id` FK of the user.

```golang
package transaction

import (
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "log"
    "github.com/pkg/errors"
)
import (
    "github.com/icrowley/fake"
)

type User struct {
    UserID int `db:"user_id"`
    UserNme string `db:"user_nme"`
    UserEmail string `db:"user_email"`
    UserAddressId sql.NullInt64 `db:"user_address_id"`
}

type ITransactionSamples interface {
    CreateUserTransaction() (*User, error)
}

type TransactionSamples struct {
    Db *sqlx.DB
}

func NewTransactionSamples(Db *sqlx.DB) ITransactionSamples {
    return &TransactionSamples{Db}
}

func (ts *TransactionSamples) CreateUserTransaction() (*User, error) {
    tx := ts.Db.MustBegin()
    var lastInsertId int
    err := tx.QueryRowx(`INSERT INTO addresses (address_id, address_city, address_country, address_state) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING address_id`, 3, fake.City(), fake.Country(), fake.State()).Scan(&lastInsertId)
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "insert address error")
    }
    log.Println("lastInsertId: ", lastInsertId)

    var user User
    err = tx.QueryRowx(`INSERT INTO users (user_id, user_nme, user_email, user_address_id) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING *;`, 6, fake.UserName(), fake.EmailAddress(), lastInsertId).StructScan(&user)
    if err != nil {
        tx.Rollback()
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "insert user error")
    }
    err = tx.Commit()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "tx.Commit()")
    }
    return &user, nil
}
```

Here is test result:

```sh
☁  transaction [master] ⚡  go test -v -count 1 ./...
=== RUN   TestCreateUserTransaction
2019/06/27 16:38:50 lastInsertId:  3
--- PASS: TestCreateUserTransaction (0.01s)
    transaction_test.go:28: &transaction.User{UserID:6, UserNme:"corrupti", UserEmail:"reiciendis_quam@Thoughtstorm.mil", UserAddressId:sql.NullInt64{Int64:3, Valid:true}}
PASS
ok      sqlx-samples/transaction        3.254s
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a sample code that works with named queries and strong type structures for inserted data and ID.

Query and struct included to cover used syntax.

```
const query = `INSERT INTO checks (
        start, status) VALUES (
        :start, :status)
        returning id;`

type Row struct {
    Status string `db:"status"`
    Start time.Time `db:"start"`
}

func InsertCheck(ctx context.Context, row Row, tx *sqlx.Tx) (int64, error) {
    return insert(ctx, row, insertCheck, "checks", tx)
}


// insert inserts row into table using query SQL command
// table used only for loging, actual table name defined in query
// should not be used from services directly - implement strong type wrappers
// function expects query with named parameters
func insert(ctx context.Context, row interface{}, query string, table string, tx *sqlx.Tx) (int64, error) {
    // convert named query to native parameters format
    query, args, err := tx.BindNamed(query, row)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("cannot bind parameters for insert into %q: %w", table, err)
    }

    var id struct {
        Val int64 `db:"id"`
    }

    err = sqlx.GetContext(ctx, tx, &id, query, args...)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("cannot insert into %q: %w", table, err)
    }

    return id.Val, nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL supports `RETURNING` syntax for `INSERT` statements.

Example:

```
INSERT INTO users(...) VALUES(...) RETURNING id, name, foo, bar
```

Documentaion: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-insert.html

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted (or updated, if an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause was used). This is primarily useful for obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as a serial sequence number. However, any expression using the table's columns is allowed. The syntax of the RETURNING list is identical to that of the output list of SELECT. Only rows that were successfully inserted or updated will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Get function:

```
db.Get(user, "INSERT INTO users (name, email) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING *", user.Name, user.Email)
```